# Is there a way to prevent simple modal from resizing images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

```
    $('a.enlarge').click(function() {
        $('#modal-image').modal({
            overlayClose: true,
            opacity: 50,
            minHeight: 462,
            minWidth: 656,
            overlayCss: {
                backgroundColor: '#fff'
            },
            appendTo: '#the-media'
        });

        return false;
    });


<div id="modal-image" style="display:none">
   <img src="someimage.jpg" width="462" height="656" id="myImage" />
</div>
```

The image is 462px x 656px but simplemodal keeps scaling it to 620px x 656px. I tried adding the minheight and minwidth arguments to the js and the width and height attributes to the image tag and even this css:

```
#myImage { width: 462px !important; height: 656px !important; }
```

but none of this is working, the image keeps being resized my simplemodal. Anyway to prevent this? I rather have the modal lightbox show the original image height and width but scroll bars if its too big to fit in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Simple modal also supports `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` according to [the documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options), if you set those as well as `minWidth` and `minHeight` you should effectively be forcing the size of the modal.

I can't comment as to whether it automatically adds a scroll bar but you can target the element yourself in CSS and apply `overflow:auto;` to the image container element if it doesn't.

Comment: no it still does it even after settings both min/max height/width to the same values.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks as though you're meant to apply your CSS using `containerCss`. Also, CSS properties in jQuery are usually wrapped up as strings.